# Adding setuid permissions to a file

Tags: permissions, chmod, setuid

I am hosting a php application on my CentOS 5 server. The application runs some commands via a ssh file called openmgr. For that I want to give a permission of `-rwsr-xr-x` to the file.

I tried `chmod +x openmgr`, but that gives `-rwxr-xr-x` permission only. How can I add `rwsr` for the file?

Comment: This is documented in `man chmod` and about two fantastillion documents searchable via Google.

Answer (score 5):

The `rws` part denotes that, `setuid` permission for the file is set. It allows the users to run/execute the file with the privileges and permissions of it's owner.

In order to enable `setuid` permission on the file mentioned in the question, you should run:

`chmod 4755 openmgr`

Or

`chmod u+s openmgr`

Answer (score 3):

You should get yourself familiar with `man chmod` (chmod(1) - change file mode bits).

- hint: `chmod 4755`.